# mysql find recent user comments

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables: user and comment.

```
create table user(
  userID int auto_increment,
  userName varchar(10),
  userCreatedDate timestamp,
  primary key(userID)
);

create table comment(
  commentID int auto-increment,
  userID int,
  comment varchar(100),
  primary key(commentID),
  foreign key(userID) references user(userID)
);
```

[image]

And I want my output like the following:
[image]

I want to find recent comment from the database:
However, I tried like this and cannot get my output:

```
select u.userID, c.commentID, u.userCreateDate
from comment c
left join userID u on c.userID = s.userID
order by u.userCreateDate desc
```

How should I modify so that I can get my output?

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to order it by the `userCreateDate` from the `user` table, because that will be the same for all comments.  It would have been nice for you to have a `commentCreateDate` but since you don't have that you can order it by the `commentID`.

Change

```
order by u.userCreateDate desc
```

to

```
order by c.commentID desc
```

Edited to add:

You also need to change your select to get the actual comment.

```
select u.userID, c.commentID, u.userCreateDate
```

should be

```
select u.userID, c.commentID, c.comment, u.userCreateDate
```

to get your desired output.  Plus I don't think you want to include `userCreateDate` in the output as people could confuse that with the date the comment was written.