# mysql find recent user comments (part 2)

Tags: mysql

Cont. on [mysql find recent user comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382548/mysql-find-recent-user-comments)

Again, 2 tables:

```
create table user(
  userID int auto_increment,
  userName varchar(10),
  userCreatedDate timestamp,
  primary key(userID)
);

create table comment(
 commentID int auto-increment,
 userID int,
 comment varchar(100),
 primary key(commentID),
 foreign key(userID) references user(userID)
);
```

[image]

This time the userCreateDate and commentID value is different from part 1.
And I want to find recent comment from the database.
My output like the following:

[image]

Here is the query that I tried:

```
select u.userID, max(c.commentID) as commentID, c.comment, u.userCreatedDate
from comment c
left join user u on c.userID = u.userID
group by u.userID
order by u.userCreateDate desc
```

However, I can't get my output. 
 
  Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as below and is called `group wise max/min` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

```
select u.*,c.comment from user u
join comment c on c.userID = u.userID
join (
 select max(commentID) as commentID,userID
 from comment group by userID
)c1 on c1.commentID = c.commentID
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query :-

```
select u.userID,commentID, c.comment, u.userCreatedDate
from comment c
left join user u on c.userID = u.userID
WHERE  commentID=(SELECT MAX(c2.commentID)
              FROM comment c2
              WHERE c.userID = c2.userID)
```